# Need assistence connecting to GitHub

Tags: git, github

Longtime Windows user here, switched to Ubuntu Desktop (latest version). I'm still a Linux Noob, and learning GIT.

**What I tried:**

When I try to login to my GitHub in the command line after trying to push, I get:

```
Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
```

I created this token, and after 3 hours of trying to figure out how the heck to actually use it, I gave up and said "Okay, SSH key time."

Followed this tutorial from start to finish and successfully made an SSH key: https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/about-ssh

I successfully linked said SSH key to GitHub.

Moment of truth!

```
git pull origin
```

Asks me for username and password. I type them in.

```
Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead.
```

Insert tears and profanities here. Literally on Windows I was never even asked for password authentication. It always just worked on Windows.

Tried figuring out this personal access token thing for another hour, still couldn't find any tutorials that explained how to permanently link it so I don't have to use it every single time I push and pull.

Tried installing:

```
sudo snap install gh
```

Messed with configuring that for a while after installing, trying to get it to work, but it keeps permission denying me. I have sudo privileges, it just won't connect to GitHub.

Spent the rest of my time trying to figure out how to use the SSH key. It is literally linked to the account already, I just need to make it use that instead of my username and password.

Comment: Did you configure `ssh` to use the corresponding private key when connecting to github.com? Also, did you change the URL for `origin` so that it uses SSH instead of HTTP to connect to your repository?

Comment: @chepner I am still sorta a noob at this, I have no clue what an SSH actually is haha. I gave GITHUB the public key and it said it linked successfully. I didn't know there was configuration for SSH. I'll see if I can find a tutorial on how to relink Origin. I had no clue you had to do that.

Comment: The URL for a Git repository generally starts with either `https://` or `ssh://`. The former means "use https protocol", which leads to the whole user-name-and-password exchange (part of https). The latter means "use ssh protocol" which doesn't have that exchange (ssh does have authentication but it's very different). You can `git clone ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git` for instance. But if you already have a repository and want to use a *short name* instead of typing in a raw URL every time, that's when you use `git remote` to create or update the name `origin`.

Comment: Maybe the simplest solution: do what you did with password auth and just use your token as the password (i.e. when asked for username, enter your username, when asked for the password, enter your token).

Answer (score 0):

Check first your GitHub remote URL

```
cd /path/to/repo
git remote -v
```

Check if it starts with `https://` or `git@github.com:...`

Regarding gh, the login should work with [`gh auth login`](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_auth_login), as in:

```
gh auth login --with-token < mytoken.txt
```

(copy your [PAT](https://docs.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/creating-a-personal-access-token) in `mytoken.txt`)